# how heroku, netlify, godaddy are different in terms of the web hosting service it provides

Tags: heroku, web-hosting, netlify

If I want to have a react app hosted on my owned domain what is my best option ?
1) Godaddy webhosting
2) heroku 
3) netlify

I not sure what are the differences, what shoud I choose, I want CI/CD to be setup and, each push to my repo on github should trigger a deployment

Answer (score 0):

Heroku and Netlify have good CI/CD support. With Netlify you are more limited since they host static web pages. You cannot do SSR (server side rendering) with Netlify.

It depends entirely on your project. If you have a project that requires SSR go for Heroku. If you have a project that is a SPA go for Netlify. When combined with GitHub it can be especially nice.